# How to approach 'selling' the Stack Exchange format to friends and colleagues?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

I'm currently working at a small private school, and would really like to get the teachers involved on SE in various areas.

I've tried enticing them with a challenge, telling them it can help to build a reputation, telling them they can also learn on here and telling them I've reached nearly 500,000 people with help for graphic design, but I haven't felt much enthusiasm from them.

**How do you approach 'selling' the SE format to friends, family or colleagues?**

<sup><sub>When I say selling, I mean getting them interested in it. I am in no way selling access to SE. :)</sub></sup>

Comment: I did look at [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166574/how-can-i-persuade-my-friends-to-join-stack-exchange) but it doesn't have much response and I feel is more targeted at students specifically. I don't mind if this is closed as a dupe, I just want some advice but can live without it.